# Wrapping a label around isometric bottle in 2D

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

I am making a poster of a bottle of pills and I wanted to wrap a label around said bottle. I created the bottle as a 2D object and not a 3D one. How can I curve a rectangular piece of art around the cylinder? I tried converting my artwork into a 3D piece but that didn't help. Been trying to sort this out a while now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This image is an example of what I want to create:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There's no real need to enter the 3D domain for this kind of illustration. In Illustrator, select your text that you want to put on the bottle and go to `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp...` and select the `Arch` option. Tweak the Bend amount (with Preview checked) to get the right amount of curve to fit the bottle label. If it's not perfect then you can use the direct selection tool to fine tune the distortion after you have applied it.